# Use SVG mask instead of clip-path transition

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, banner, clip-path

I've created a working prototype of what will eventually be a hero banner where

- the script cycles through each section
- transitions to each section use a expanding shape to reveal the next section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hero Banner Animation</title>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: none;
        }

        .section {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100vw; /* Use viewport width */
            height: 100vh; /* Use viewport height */
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            opacity: 0;
            clip-path: circle(0% at 50% 50%);
            transition: clip-path 1.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        @keyframes revealCircle {
            0% {
                clip-path: circle(0% at 50% 50%);
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                clip-path: circle(100% at 50% 50%);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="headline">
            <h1>Greetings</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-image: url('https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1682123600420-a54096da1156?q=80&w=2928&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D');">
        <div class="headline">
            <h1>Headline 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506102383123-c8ef1e872756?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D');">
        <div class="headline">
            <h1>Headline 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547626740-02cb6aed9ef8?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D');">
        <div class="headline">
            <h1>Headline 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
    const totalSections = sections.length;
    let currentSectionIndex = 0;

    function animateCircle() {
        const currentSection = sections[currentSectionIndex];

        // Reset clip-path and opacity for the current section
        currentSection.style.clipPath = 'circle(0% at 50% 50%)';
        currentSection.style.opacity = 0;

        // Apply keyframes using animation
        currentSection.style.animation = 'revealCircle 1.5s ease-in-out forwards';

        // Add event listener for the animationend event
        currentSection.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
            // Reset clip-path and opacity for the current section before moving to the next one
            currentSection.style.clipPath = 'circle(0% at 50% 50%)';
            currentSection.style.opacity = 0;

            // Increment to the next section index
            currentSectionIndex = (currentSectionIndex + 1) % totalSections;

            // Continue with the next section
            animateCircle();
        }, { once: true });
    }

    // Start the animation loop
    animateCircle();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

1. I would like to change this script to use a SVG mask vs the clip-path circle as I have a custom shape (not a circle) that I'd like to use for the transitions
2. Right now, it's stopping on the last section and I can't figure out how to make it continuous starting from the first section